# Question on velocity and acceleration

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

You're on top of a ship's main mast with the ship moving forward and you let a ball fall. Will the ball fall in front, behind or right at the base of the main mast?

I think the answer is: the ball will fall at the base of the main mast if the velocity of the ship will remain constant, in front if the ship will decelerate and behind if the ship will have positive acceleration.

Is it right?

Comment: Very much like dropping something in your car while driving.  Easy enough to test yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right.

Just before the ball starts falling, it has the same veocity as the ship. During the fall, it maintains that forward velocity relative to the earth so that, if the ship's velocity remains constant, it will fall right at the base of the main mast.  If the ship accelerates during the period when the ball is falling, it will fall behind the main mast; in front of the main mast if the ship decellerates.

Comment: Well to be a little more accurate ( this is just for the sake of completion ) , it will be not 'right at the base of the main mast' , but a little away from it . This is for something called the "Corriolis Effect". This is tangential component of acceleration which generally arises when a body both rotates (here because of the earth) and also has radial displacement. But this of course is more pronounced in case the height is large , otherwise negligible. But the the question more tries to find your knowledge of relative velocity than "Corriolis Affect". In that sense this answer is sufficient

Comment: @BarunDasgupta, we also neglected the drag force due to the forward velocity of the ship.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right. (Answer must contain at least 30 characters, but I really do not know what else to say about it)

Comment: Yes, that is the problem of such posts. We discourage generally such queries which simply can be answered by yes/no.

Comment: Possibly you can mention the air resistance, a few more words.